# What Mario-like game is this?

Tags: game-identification

[image: Cropped screenshot of a Mario-like game]

What Mario-like game is this? The original screenshot is from an iPad.

Answer (score 12):

That looks to be Super Smash Bros. Melee. Specifically, it is the [Mushroom Kingdom Adventure Mode](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Mushroom_Kingdom_%28Adventure_Mode%29).

Here is another screenshot from a different portion of the level

[image: Mushroom Kingdom Adventure Mode]

Image from the wiki page linked above. And here's a video of the level in action. At about 40 seconds in, you will see the portion that is contained in your screenshot.

Comment: That's still the wrong screenshots.  You're at 2 edits so far, but that screenshot is from Brawl, not from Melee

Comment: @memescientist The screenshot was taken from the Wiki page related to the level. Which I will credit and make it 3 edits ;P

Comment: @memescientist This adventure mode level doesn't exist in Brawl, so how is the screenshot from brawl?

Comment: I edited the youtube video to start when you see the screen Op posted

Answer (score 4):

It's actually the first stage of **Super Smash Bros Melee**'s Adventure mode.

From [here:](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Mushroom_Kingdom_%28Adventure_Mode%29)

> Mushroom Kingdom (sometimes also called Mushroom Kingdom III or
>   Mushroom Kingdom Adventure) is the first stage of Super Smash Bros.
>   Melee 's Adventure Mode. Its design is reminiscent of classic Mario
>   platforming levels, complete with Goombas, Koopa Troopas, and Koopa
>   Paratroopas.

The reason it's Melee is because of the Damage Percentage display on the lower left hand corner.  This is another screenshot from Melee's regular mode. If you look on the lower left, it clearly matches up with the lower left of your screenshot:

[image]

Your screenshot in question:

[image]